# https.request returning incomplete stream

Tags: node.js, http, node-streams

`https.request` returns correct data, but when I pipe the response into a file, it is incomplete, and missing a lot at the beginning.

How I am using `https.request`:

```js
import client from "https";

const _request = (url, options, timeout) => {
    let data = '';
    const httpOptions = {};
    const parsedUrl = new URL(url);

    const hostname = parsedUrl.hostname;
    const port = parsedUrl.port;
    const path = parsedUrl.pathname;
    const params = parsedUrl.search;

    httpOptions["hostname"] = hostname;
    httpOptions["port"] = port;
    httpOptions["path"] = path + params;
    httpOptions["method"] = options.method.toUpperCase() || "GET";

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = client.request(httpOptions, (res) => {
            if (options.stream === true) resolve(res);

            res.on("data", (chunk) => {
                data += chunk;
            });

            res.on("end", () => {
                resolve({
                    status: res.statusCode,
                    statusText: res.statusMessage,
                    data: data,
                });
            });

            res.on("error", (err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
        });

        req.end();
    });
};
```

How I'm trying to stream the response:

```js
import client from "./index.js";
import { createWriteStream } from "fs";

const response = await client("an.api.that/returns-plain-text", {
    method: "GET",
    stream: true
}, 5000);

const writeStream = createWriteStream("./test.txt");
response.pipe(writeStream);
```

I've tried moving `if (options.stream === true) resolve(res);` inside `req.on("end")`, however that resulted in the same issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement `res.on("data", ...)` causes the response to start emitting `data` events immediately. If you write something like

```js
_request(url, {stream: true}, timeout)
.then(function(res) {
  res.pipe(createWriteSteam(...));
});
```

then by the time the `res.pipe` statement is reached, `res` may already have emitted some data, which is then lost (so the beginning of the response will be missing, as you observed).

To prevent the premature emitting of `data` events, you can explicitly [pause](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/stream.html#readablepause) the stream:

```js
if (options.stream === true) {
  res.pause();
  resolve(res);
}
```